# Generate and download Zip file on the fly in (client-side) JS

Tags: javascript, zip

I have n Javascript float arrays. 
My goal is to generate and download a Zip file, using JS only, containing n CSV files, one per array.

I am aware of Javascript librairies like JSZip: http://stuk.github.io/jszip/ for generating zip files.
I also know how to generate and download a file on the fly using Blob and/or a library like FileSaver.js

However, I cannot figure out how to achieve the whole thing, client-side only.

Can anybody help me ?